# Is there any alternative to OpenDNS?

Tags: internet, opendns

Is there any alternative to OpenDNS? Do you know of any service that is similar to OpenDNS?

Comment: Symantec has come out with Norton DNS. Haven't used it? Anyone?

Comment: quad9 is a DNS service oriented towards privacy and security, you may want to give it a go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends which features of OpenDNS you use - if you want the extra filtering and other such your options may be more limited. Also, telling us why you are looking for alternatives (nxdomain handling? reliability problems? just curious?) would help in getting good answers.

Google have recent started a public DNS service, as stated by Paul's response, which may suit your needs.

If you run your own servers or virtual servers then you could also run your own private DNS service, but as this question is on SO not SF I'm guessing you are a home user rather than a server/IT admin so that would probably be massively over-kill for you!

Comment: I want a faster and safer browsing

Comment: Define "safer". OpenDNS offers a phishing filter and other such filters, where Google's DNS currently does not (see the bottom of "Google Public DNS: what it is and isn't" on http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/intro.html)

Answer (score 11):

[Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

Comment: +1 But actually doesn't support domain block.

Comment: +1, because it's really fast - the main advantage of oDNS.

Answer (score 2):

Many people have good speeds with Level 3's DNS.

That's `4.2.2.1` to `4.2.2.6`, so very easy to remember.

Google have a good new DNS service, at `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`, so ALSO easy to remember.

UltraDNS is very similar to OpenDNS, in that it tries to provide a little more control, but I've never used it, and it doesn't appear to be free.

Answer (score 1):

[ClearCloud DNS](http://clearclouddns.com/) is a new beta kid on the block.

Good at malware alerts. Advertises on the twit network. If used with OpenDNS, you may see warnings.

Answer (score 1):

DNS Redirector has been available 3 years prior to OpenDNS, in some cases you may benefit from OpenDNS, but in some cases your ISP's DNS servers will be faster.

Use [this](http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm) tool to determine which DNS service is the fastest for you, then implement [DNS redirector](http://www.dnsredirector.com) software for filtering and control.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've been playing with [DNSadvantage](http://www.DNSadvantage.com) tonight. It does the worst job of resolving bad url's than anything I have ever seen, but browsing is faster than a scalded hound! I'll stick with it for the time being because of the performance improvement over OpenDNS, but I still want something better